# UIView --> UIImage for non-visible view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, watchkit

I'm trying to go work around the inability to use custom UI elements in Watchkit. My app uses custom UIButtons (MRoundedbutton) and what I'm trying to do is replicate them on the Watchkit interface by creating images of them and using that as the background for the WKInterfaceButton. The problem is that I'm not able to convert UIViews to UIImage when the view isn't visible. This is the code I'm using, it's giving me an index out of bounds error on `drawViewHierarchyInRect`.

```
- (UIImage *)convertButtontoImage:(MRoundedButton *)button
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(button.bounds.size, YES, 0);

    [button drawViewHierarchyInRect:button.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return image;
}
```

Since there is really no screen/window in a Watchkit extension, how would we go about creating images from would-be views?

Comment: Your code seems OK, and the index out of bounds error is unexpected, perhaps this suggests that there is a bug in the custom button your are using?

Comment: The problem is that a UIView doesn't seem to have a subview cache unless it's attached to a superview/window. The index out of bounds error is occurring when drawViewHierarchyInRect attempts to go through the subview cache.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than drawViewHierarchyInRect, try using renderInContext on the layer.

I just ran into the same problem you describe.  Using drawViewHierarchInRect didn't work - just get a black screen.  But after switching to renderInContext, it looks like I'm able to convert a UIView to UIImage from my app while it's in background (so without the view being visible on the screen), and then I can send it over to the watch and it's displayed.

Here's what I used:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
//    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return capturedImage;
}
```

Then I use openParentApplication from WatchKit Extension to ping the phone, then convert the UIImage to NSData in order to pass it back in handleWatchKitExtensionRequest.  Looks like it's working for me so far, so hopefully it will for you too.  This was all done on the simulator, btw.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise against what you are trying to do. Rendering your iOS button to a bitmap, then sending it over the wire to the watch each time is going to put a heavy load on the watch - sending one-off image data over the bluetooth connection. I predict it will be quite slow, and also chew through the battery faster than normal.

Better to do this once, and install the image into the storyboard for your watch kit app.

As to your specific question, I don't think that method works offscreen. If you read the docs on drawViewHierarchyInRect, they say:

> Renders a snapshot of the complete view hierarchy **as visible
>   onscreen** into the current context.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Well the images would be quite small, hopefully there wouldn't be too much of a performance hit. I could cache them on the watch or add them to the storyboard but they need to reflect their current state and data model which is going to change. As far as what the docs say, I understand that much and I know that's why my code isn't working. I'm just trying to figure out a workaround.

Comment: another non-useful non-answer. Why do you even bother?  <snipped grumpy insults> @joseph, the next answer is a good one.

Comment: @eric, sometimes "don't do that" is an appropriate answer to a question. I felt, and continue to feel, that this is such a case. Damian's answer does address how to do it if the OP decides to use that approach.

Comment: Sorry to come at you on tis @DuncanC. Sometimes I get frustrated with SO answers like this one. Where the answerer feels more like a switch to the back of the knuckles, then actually helping the asker. And, really the reason I do not participate on SO as much as I should.

Comment: On the topic of sending hand built images to the watch. I've done that, it can be quite performant (when used for the right reasons, probably not when you are trying to render out a button.). It allowed me to do the right thing for the different screen sizes, with content coming from the inter webs (can't install the image on the storyboard). :-)